# Why my ActivityMainBinding is showing error?

Tags: android, data-binding

I was using binding object. My button id in the main activity xml file was 'button' but in the java class its showing red color on button in binding.button

[image]

```
package com.example.admybrand_git_api;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.google.android.material.progressindicator.BaseProgressIndicator;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ActivityMainBinding binding;

@Override
protected void onCreate(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
    binding.button.setOnClickListener(view->{
       Intent intent = new Intent(this,Git_Id_searchpage.class)
    });
    return binding.getroot();
}}
```

Comment: Have you tried cleaning and rebuilding the project? Is the binding active in the gradle? Also post your xml file.

Comment: `onCreate` return type is void why are you returning the View here ?  Also you need to Override the other variant of `onCreate` which should be `protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)` ..

Answer (score 0):

You didn't add necessary information so let's guess.
Check if:

1. you added this code to build.gradle

buildFeatures {
viewBinding true
dataBinding true
}

2. added necessary import in your Activity
3. it has the same name as your **XML layout** (not Activity class)
4. You don't need

> setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

if you use ViewBinding

Answer (score 0):

if you are using data binding then be ensure you have implemented it correctly.
your layout should start with `<layout>` and also end with `</layout>`.

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

  <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
     tools:context=".activities.MainActivity">

     <!--your activity code design -->


  </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

and you don't need to `setContentView` and `infalteView` both for single layout bind your layout with `DataBindinngUtils`.

**MainActivity.class**

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity  {

ActivityMainBinding activityMainBinding;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    activityMainBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);

      activityMainBinding.button.setOnClickListener(view-> {
       Intent intent = new Intent(this,Git_Id_searchpage.class)
      });

 }
```